# Font Awesome aparecem caracteres estranhos

Tags: css, font

Alguns icones font-awesome não aparecem, outros no lugar de ícone aparece 'fl'.

Estou usando normalmente,

```
<i class="fa fa-search"></i>
```

Importando o css pelo

https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css

No Firefox, ao inves dos caracteres estranhos, aparecem blocos com texto variavel, sempre começando com 'f', no geral assim: 'f002', 'f14e'.
No Console não é exibido nada.

Comment: Já tentou limpar o cache do navegador? Testar no chrome?

Comment: tenta com essa url: https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.1.0/css/font-awesome.min.css

Comment: Limpei o cache  e mudei a url como dissem, nada :(

Comment: Já testou em outro computador?

Comment: Sim @Orion, temos 2 computador aqui.

Comment: A única explicação pra isso é algum conflito, não faz sentido isso acontecer só no seu projeto.

Comment: Me parece um erro na codificação ou um arquivo corrompido, não pode ser reproduzido. Forneça um exemplo do problema no jsfiddle por exemplo.

Comment: De fato @GuilhermeNascimento era um erro de codificação, o web designer colocou !important na importação de outra fonte :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Experimenta trocar para essa url: https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.1.0/css/font-awesome.min.css

Ou se estiver utilizando `Apache`, inclua no **.htaccess**:

```
<FilesMatch "\.(ttf|otf|eot|woff)$">
  <IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
  </IfModule>
</FilesMatch>
```

Comment: não funcionou, continua do mesmo jeito, mais, alguma ideia do que possa ser isso?

Comment: tentou baixar o arquivo pro servidor junto com a segunda solução?

Comment: Inicialmente comecei a usar com o arquivo css no servidor, mas, acentecia a mesma coisa.